# putcsv formatting wrong when result is from pdo

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo, fputcsv

I am trying to import data from a db via pdo and output the results to a csv file. I am able to output to a screen correctly but the formatting in the csv is wild, double names and no '\n'

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pw);

if (($handle = fopen("nameList2.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "        ")) !== FALSE) {
                $firstname = $data[0];
                $lastname = $data[1];
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE FName = :firstname AND LName = :lastname");
                $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
                $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                //var_dump($firstname);
                //var_dump($lastname);
                //var_dump($result);
                $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
                foreach($result as $chunk){
                        echo $chunk[4]."        ".$chunk[6]."   ".$chunk[7]."   ".$chunk[10]."  ".$chunk[11]."".$chunk[12]."  ".$chunk[13]."  ".$chunk[18]."  ".$chunk[19]."  ".$chunk[20]."<br />";
                        fputcsv($fp, $chunk);
                }
                fclose($fp);
        }
        fclose($handle);
        //fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with double names is because you doesn't use the method fetchAll() right:
you get the names twice in the $result.
Use that:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To fix the problem with \n try

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Comment: PDO::FETCH_ASSOC seams to blow out my query all together   ->  Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /blah/query2.php on line 19

Comment: yes, it borks my line 19 which is no big deal, I just commented it out. But actually PDO::FETCH_ASSOC does similar to the recommendation above, outputs the first row but nothing else. It seems to lose the rest of the query. http://i.imgur.com/6NSMEBP.png  <- as you can see from a var_dump, the data is there, but never reaches the csv

Comment: oh, change $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w'); to $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');

Comment: fopen('file.csv', 'a');   fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding `fputcsv` bad data, so it's giving you bad output. Specifically, `fetchAll` retrieves each row as an array with both numeric and string keys, so each value appears twice.

Fix this by setting the fetch mode appropriately, for example

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

It's unclear what the problem with the line endings is -- you don't say, and I can't tell from the screenshot. What is certain is that `fputcsv` writes a single line feed as the line termination character. While the vast majority of programs will correctly detect and handle these Unix-style line endings, there are some others (e.g. Notepad) that won't.

Comment: Thank you, that cleaned it up a lot. a little too much actually. It outputs the first row correctly and that's all. Only one, not the rest.   :/

Comment: any  thoughts on how I can get the rest of the data?